# How do I create a loop over non consecutive integers from data in a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python to break up a csv files. Each file has three columns, one of which is just integers. The integers are not consecutive and for each integer there are multiple rows of data I want to pull out and write to separate .dat file. For example, I want to pull all the data for 7 or 8 different integers, say 0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9 or 6, 7, 9, 13, 14, 16, 18, 21, 22. The table in the csv file looks like this:

```
0,0,0.751622894
0,0.760816637,0.732487133
1,0.01176769,0.761377432
1,0.263682475,0.770548537
1,0.768830839,0.731812798
2,0.020187674,0.764187624
2,0.777022572,0.74336139
3,0.046867867,0.771258565
6,0.83768704,0.756484441
7,0.104007101,0.785597332
9,0.847070758,0.751622894
9,0.867841745,0.754397082
13,0.923966523,0.764187624
14,0.176667512,0.795060175
16,0.993608927,0.772680585
18,0.00887649,0.776247117
21,0.01285823,0.779112191
21,0.257595739,0.798730006
21,0.77428354,0.767008188
22,0.527212782,0.719780373
22,0.78840984,0.764891791
```

I have code, but it only works if the integers are consecutive.

```
    starting_rotation_list = []   
    i=0
    #current rotation leaving the last loop is the max rotation number
    while(i < current_rotation):
        if i in Dict.keys():
            if i+1 in Dict.keys():
                if i+2 in Dict.keys():
                    if i+3 in Dict.keys():
                        if i+4 in Dict.keys():
                            if i+5 in Dict.keys():
                                if i+6 in Dict.keys():
                                    starting_rotation_list.append(i)
    i = i+1
```

The code runs with no error, but does not create the desired .dat fills because the integers are not consecutive. If I code the loop to run for fewer integers, say 2 or 3 it will also work fine, but I need this to work for 7 or 8.

Comment: what is `Dict` and why calling it `Dict` ?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include desired output?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `defaultdict` to collect each row matching your wanted integer number. Once all rows have been read in the resulting `data` dictionary can then be written one at a time to a different output CSV file. The following shows how this could be done, the output CSV filenames have the format `output_0.csv` etc...

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

req_values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9]
data = defaultdict(list)

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        if int(row[0]) in req_values:
            data[row[0]].append(row)

for value in data:
    with open(f'output_{value}.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
        csv_output.writerows(data[value])
```

Answer (score 0):

You apparently assigned a dictionary like `{0: .761, 1: .769, ... }` to `Dict`.
[PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) asks that you please don't do that.
Identifiers are not just unique and used by the machine;
they are meaningful to humans as well.
We use initial lowercase for variables such as a dictionary,
and initial uppercase when defining a new class.

It appears you want to know if at least K observations
occurred within a fixed window of some initial integer.
Here is code that computes that:

```
import collections
import pprint

window = 7
s = set([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 9, 13, 14, 16, 18, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22])
# s = set(Dict.keys())
total = collections.defaultdict(int)
for val in s:
    for i in range(window):
        total[val + i] += 1

pprint.pprint(total)
```

Now you can compare `total[n]` to some desired threshold,
perhaps `k = 4`, to see if there were enough observations near `n`.